# Weird IndexOUBException using buttons inside listview

Tags: android, listview

I am having a very strange issue in an activity using a listview that contains buttons.

The error seems to pop up kind of randomly (although we know that doesn't really exist), i mean to say I cant get a defined pattern to reproduce the error. It just happens every so often.

The big issue i'm having trying to figure this out is the logCat shows no error in my code, just in the code that (i believe) android uses to determine the view where the click is coming from. Take notice that no package that doesnt belong to android/java is mentioned in the error.

LogCat:

```
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Arrays.java:77)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:298)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:351)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.widget.Spinner.makeAndAddView(Spinner.java:189)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:148)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:112)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7032)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7032)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1238)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1044)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7032)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7032)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7032)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7032)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7032)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1055)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1737)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-14 12:04:20.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5619):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my custom ArrayAdapter code, the error occurs when I click on various "boton_modificar" from the various rows repeatedly, mostly if I click them fastly.

```
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataType> {

  public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<DataType> objects) {
   super(context, resource, objects);
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View row = convertView;

   final int position2 = position;

   if (row == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
   }

   //Some more code here

   ImageButton boton_modificar = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.modificar);
   boton_modificar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
     DataT t = tr.get(position2);
     ((EditText) (findViewById(R.id.monto))).setText(Double.toString(t.m));
     ((Spinner) (findViewById(R.id.spinnerTipoB))).setSelection(t.posSTB);
     ((Spinner) (findViewById(R.id.spinnerB))).setSelection(t.posSB);
    }
   });
   return (row);
  }
 }
```

Does anybode have the slightest idea what this might be? Im tired of trying to figure this out and nothing. Most I found was a bug report of a similar issue, but I doubt its the same thing, in any case [the report is here.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8450)

Thanks in advance, Stefano

Edit:

LogCat of just before the error pops, doubt it has anything to do with the position sets.

```
12-16 15:12:56.159: INFO/position2(21828): 7
12-16 15:12:56.159: INFO/Spinner A # elements:(21828): 3
12-16 15:12:56.159: INFO/Assigned position(21828): 1
12-16 15:12:56.159: INFO/Spinner B # elements:(21828): 20
12-16 15:12:56.159: INFO/Assigned position(21828): 5
```

Added code:

```
spinnerTipoB.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int position, long arg3) {
                        int posId = tipoBIds[position];
                        if (posId == 0) {
                                spinnerB.setAdapter(arrayAdapterBP);
                        } else if (posId == 1) {
                            spinnerB.setAdapter(arrayAdapterBT);
                        } else if (posId == 2) {
                            spinnerB.setAdapter(arrayAdapterBO);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // Do Nothing
                    }
                });
```

`spinnerB` does nothing on position select.
All spinner array adapter are created like this:

```
arrayAdapterNAME = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.layoutspinner, DATA);
```

I would presume the error ocurrs because `((Spinner) (findViewById(R.id.spinnerB))).setSelection(t.posSB);` is executed before `spinnerB.setAdapter(arrayAdapterNAME)`is done?

Comment: No headers and footers anywhere. `tr` is an ArrayList and the data is there, im not getting a NPE. My code isnt even getting to those lines, when it crashes, it does so before entering the clickListener.

Comment: verify that `position2` inside the `onClick` method is the proper integer value by Logging it to `LogCat`.  Looks like the problem is near the 2 `setSelection` method calls.

Comment: I have a feeling that `position2` is not what you might think it is, since it's being accessed inside on `onClick` event method which is inside this `getView` method.  i have worked around this problem in my own project, let me know if you find that `position2` is not what you expect

Comment: Edited, that seems fine, the numbers are always in range.

Comment: Does "//Some more code" has any code, that deals with the list?
Btw. You won't be getting NPE if your position is > than list.size(), you'll be getting "out of bounds".

Comment: Some more code is just the build of the list, I include a button to eliminate that row, that works perfectly. It just breaks when using the edit button, not the delete button.

Comment: I have a theory, when I press the edit button, the code changes spinners A position, which in turn changes the adapter used by spinner B, and changes the position set by spinner B. Is it possible that sometimes spinner B is still doing something related to the adapter change when my code tries to change the set position?

Comment: Is 'tr' a reference to the same List instance that the ArrayAdapter is constructed with? If not, that's a problem... use getItem() instead of tr.get(). A screenshot would be great... I'm not sure if these spinners are inside the list or out of it, or where the buttons are, or what the buttons might do etc...

Comment: Btw, you did notice that your crash is in the adapter tied to the *spinner* rather than any *listview*, right? The question says listview at the top, so I assumed that the adapter code is for the listview adapter, not any spinners...

Comment: Yes, I noticed that the issues comes from the spinners, that were I got my theory from. The buttons are in the list, meaning each row has an edit and delete button. The spinners are outside of the list.
The adapter used here is for the list.

Comment: tr is the data set upon which the list is built, I have changed that now, it doesnt change the behavior at all. The reason I find some relation between the list and the problem is that it only ocrrus when the list has about 7+ items, before it doesnt happen. The adapter for the spinners are regular `ArrayAdapters<String>`.

Comment: You need to post all code pertaining to the spinner adapters... when they're created, what modifies their data, etc. Apart from the button click handling, the listview adapter is a red herring.

Comment: Are you thinking that setSelection() would cause the onItemSelectedListener event to run before setSelection returns? It doesn't work that way afaik, so your supposition is correct. Set the spinner adapter from the button onClick() and *then* set the selected indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with the `ListView's` adapter and everything to do with the `Spinner` adapter.

When you click one of your buttons you call `setSelection()` on both spinners. If you check the code in [`AbsSpinner.setSelection(int)`](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/AbsSpinner.java&q=android%20AbsSpinner&d=4&l=272) you'll see that it caches the integer index of the newly selected item and calls `requestLayout()` to redraw itself (at some later point).

When the UI thread processes the layout messages, it lays out everything in the view tree but blows up when laying out a Spinner because the index it cached earlier is no longer valid. Something has altered the adapter's list... this must have happened in response to a UI event such (as a Button onClick()) and which got processed before the layout message being processed.

**ADDED LATER FOLLOWING COMMENTS DISCUSSION AND CODE ADDED TO O.P.**:

The wrong assumption was that `Spinner.setSelection()` would cause the `onItemSelectedListener` event to run before it returned. The fix for this specific problem was to set the spinner adapter from the button onClick() and then set selected indexes afterwards.